# I need help constructing a $n\times n$ matrix with determinant $1$ that moves the unit vector $e_{1}=col(1,0,0,..0)$ to a non-zero vector $x$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help constructing a $n\times n$ matrix with determinant $1$ that moves the unit vector $e_{1}=(1,0,0,..0)^T$ to a non-zero vector $x$ in $X=R^n\setminus\{0\}$.

I need to use it to prove that a certain group action is transitive.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $\:$ " $R^n$ ~ {$0$} " $\:$ ? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: That's not a great remark, but you need $n\geq 2$ for this to be true for every nonzero $X$.

Comment: If you can do it for $n=2$, you will have no problem generalizing. Treat the cases $x_1\neq 0$ and $x_1=0$ separately. In the latter case, you must have $x_2\neq 0$ so just take $A$ to be $(0,-x_2^{-1})(x_2,0)$. You say you are ok with the former case, so all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Let the matrix be $A$  You want $Ae_1=X$ so the first column of $A$ should be $X$.  Then to make the determinant $1$, make $A_{22}$ the inverse of $A_{11}$ and fill the rest of the diagonal with $1$'s and all the other positions with $0$.  Can you see why this works?  The only problem comes if the first element of $X$ is zero.  It isn't hard to patch up.

Added:  fixed row to column.  for three dimensions, $$A=\begin {pmatrix} X_1&0&0 \\ X_2&1/X_1&0\\X_3&0&1\end {pmatrix}$$

Comment: yes i have that much, i am only having problem with the case where the first element of X is zero.Can u help me with that?

Comment: @uh1:  Then pick a non-zero entry.  You want one diagonal to have non-zero entries and every other diagonal to have at least one zero.  Then fill with ones except for one that is $\pm$ the non-zero entry of interest.

Comment: Small correction: The first *column* of $A$ needs to be $X$. :)

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks for replying but can you please write it down if you have time, its hard to understand otherwise. i will be really grateful if you can explain by writing this matrix you are describing.

Comment: i meant can you write down for the case where $X_{1}$=0. If you can't write down for nxn, a 4x4 will also be very much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: @uh1:  think about how in the case $X_1 \neq 0$ every (broken) diagonal that you would multiply to form the determinant has a zero in it except the main one.  You need to reproduce that in the case $X_1=0$.  The easiest way is to use the $21$ and $12$ coordinates, plus the rest of the main diagonal